# AWS ECS get placement constraint after task creation

Tags: amazon-ecs

I am trying to create a CI build step that will stop and re-run my tasks when my docker containers changed.

The definition itself would be pointing at `latest` tag in ECR, and so all i need is to `stop-task` and then `run-task`.

Two of the parameters in the API as well as the UI are `PlacementConstraints` and `PlacementStrategy`.

Is there any way to get these from the API AFTER the task has been started? e.g. get them for a running task. `describe-tasks` doesn't seem to return this information.

Comment: Have you considered running your tasks as services? If you were to do that, could build your images tagged with the build number and `latest`, and then have a cloudformation template that takes the build number, generates the new task, and updates the service for you (bringing the new tasks online, and cleaning up the old ones). If that sounds interesting, let me know, and I can give you more details.

Comment: @JamieStarke i did go with that in the end, but i still want to know how to get these parameters from the API.